# Bootstrap popover shifting

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

How can I achieve the following with bootstrap popover:

[image: popover shifted]

Where the popover is displayed far right of the element that was triggered.
fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10435/
I would like the popover outside of the panel.

Updating the `left` (or some other position) rule of the popover css (with javascript) doesn't help since it is overridden when the popover is shown.
And if I change the position on the `shown.bs.popover` event then the original positioning is shown for a few miliseconds.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can override popover's positioning using !important in css. Might not be a very elegant solution, but it works.

```
.panel-body .popover {
    left: 20px !important;
}
```

Check this code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover();
    
});
```

```css
.panel {
    width:50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.panel-body .popover {
    left: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <input type="text" id="text_input" data-toggle="popover"
        data-content="blah" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="left"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you..yes, it's not too elegant. It seems like a very common case so I would think there is something more elegant.